# How to fix my nested model form redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-forms

I have a signup process that goes:

```
user = User.new
user.email = ...
user.password = ...
user.profile = Profile.new
user.profile.save
user.save
```

In my app I initiate the signup process on the homepage through an `InfoController` to handle static pages. Because the form on the homepage mixes the `user` and `profile` models, I am using a nested model form. However, when I submit the form I am redirected to the wrong place. Can anyone help me figure out what I did wrong?

**Routes.rb file:**

```
match '/login' => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
match '/signup' => 'profiles#new', :as => "signup"
match 'skip/signup', :to => 'info#signupskip'
match 'skip/profiles/new', :to => 'profiles#newskip'

root :to => 'info#home'
root :to => "questions#index"
resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :info
resource :session
resources :session
```

**ProfilesController:**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def name
    puts "#{user.profile.first_name} #{user.profile.last_name}"
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to profile_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  ...
```

**UsersController:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @user = User.all
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to profile_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

**And finally, the form with nested models:**

```
  <%= form_for(:profile, :url => 'signup', :html => {:id => 'homepage'}) do |f| %>
    <p class="hometext">I'm&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :first_name, :placeholder => 'First name' %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, :size=> 8, :id => "profile[first_name]" %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="profile[last_name]">Last name</label>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, :size=> 8, :id => "profile[last_name]" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.fields_for :user do |f| %>
    <p class="hometext">.&nbsp;My&nbsp;email&nbsp;is&nbsp;
      <div>
        <label for="user[email]">Email</label>
        <%= f.text_field :email, :size=> 13, :id => "user[email]" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <p class="hometext">.&nbsp;I want to&nbsp;</p>
    <div>
      <label for="user[goal]">ex: be President</label>
      <%= f.text_field :goal, :size=> 13, :id => "user[goal]" %>
    </div>
    <p class="hometext">when I grow up.&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="button">
      <%= submit_tag 'Join', :class => 'button orange' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `<%= form_for(:user) .. %>` and then `<%= fields_for :profile .. %>` ?

Comment: I tried that too and still get the same redirect unfortunately.

Comment: Following up with a link to a similar question with :user first in the nested model form - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224881/nested-model-form-not-working-properly-need-to-pinpoint-post-get-redirect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following route is incorrect:

`match '/signup' => 'profiles#new', :as => "signup"`

In your `form_for`, you're specifying that it's for `:profile`. By default, Rails would `POST` this to `profiles#create`. Since you're passing `:url => 'signup'`, the form is actually being `POST`ed to `/signup`, which is mapped, via the aforementioned route, to `profiles#new`. However, the `new` action simply sets up the form — it's the action you first started on. That being said, the correct route should be:

`match '/signup' => 'profiles#create', :as => "signup"`

In fact, if you wanted to make it that much better, it should be this:

`post '/signup' => 'profiles#create', :as => "signup"`

Further, since you're using a named route (by passing `as` in the route), you should be using `:url => signup_path` in your `form_for`.

As a quick aside: I'm not quite sure what your models look like, but I'd probably agree with Kleber here. It seems more intuitive that it should be `form_for :user` instead.

Comment: Thanks!! Yeah, I actually got rid of the InfoController step and now have form_for :user in the UsersController new method.

Comment: I think I'm on the right path. I had to edit my `before_filter :authenticate` in my ProfilesController. Whoops, I overlooked that!