# Nested model form not working properly - need to pinpoint POST/GET redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a nested model form that isn't functioning properly. The POST is to the proper place, but then the GET reroutes me. So I'm wondering if anyone can help explain what I'm doing wrong.

I have two models: `User` and `Profile`. Code for them below:

**User:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password, :email
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  ...
end
```

**Profile:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, etc.
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  ...
end
```

New/Create from both models:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    if logged_in?
      redirect_to current_user.profile
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to signup_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to profile_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @profile = current_user.profile
  end
```

My signup (two step process) mixes the models, so as I said I'm using a nested model form in my Users `new.html.erb` file. Code `form_for` and `f.fields_for` below:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => signup_path, :html => {:id => 'homepage'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :profile do |f| %>
```

Now when I enter data into the form, my routes.rb file seems to POST to the proper place (`/signup` so profile can be filled out further), but GET routes me to `/login`.

**Routes.rb**:

```
match '/login' => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
match '/signup' => 'profiles#new', :as => "signup"
match 'skip/signup', :to => 'info#signupskip'
match 'skip/profiles/new', :to => 'profiles#newskip'
root :to => 'users#new'
resources :users
resources :profiles
```

In `rails server`:

```
Started POST "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Aug 28 19:54:11 -0400 2011
  Processing by ProfilesController#new as HTML

Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Aug 28 19:54:11 -0400 2011
  Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (32.1ms)
```

I'm wondering if the problem is in my `layouts/application` file, specifically this code:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <%= render 'layouts/header_in' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'layouts/header_out' %>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone help explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I deleted the if/else argument in `layouts/application' and it was still redirected. So I'm back to wondering what's going on.

Comment: The problem here seems to be related with your authentication system.

Comment: I'm new to programming/Rails in general, so can you help me pinpoint where in my app I should be looking to fix the issue?

Comment: So you can have the User profile created successful? Do you see the messsage `User successfully added.` ?

Comment: No I don't. I thought I couldn't see it because I have a redirect from the root to signup, which is supposed to be Profiles#New.

Comment: Okay, in order to be able to create a new profile you should be logged in first. Also paste in the `index` method from your `ProfilesController`

Comment: So I can't create the profile as part of my sign-up process? Index method above.

Comment: @KleberS. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2964/discussion-between-tvalent2-and-kleber-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem has to do with an inherent issue (though arguably not problem) with HTTP protocol. You cannot return a redirect to a POST request. Alternatives include calling the other method from within the first controller action, or rendering the correct page directly from that action, or some mix of both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm new to programming/Rails, but in terms of calling the other method, do you mean the profile method? I tried to also force the action in the form but perhaps I did that incorrectly? Could you give me some examples with code by chance?

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you want to happen, but just taking a look, I think maybe it has to do with `UsersController.new`. If that is called as a POST it will not redirect, but stick with the expected route. If it is called from a GET statement (via a redirect or named route) then it will redirect to ProfilesController RESTFUL route. Could you specify which call is doing what, and what you would like it to do instead? That would be more helpful.

Comment: What I want to do is have the main signup process form accept both `user` and `profile` info. After submitting that, the user is taken to another form where they fill in the rest of the `user` and `profile` info. Then when they save that form, they are directed to their profile. (Of course they can skip that process and just go to one integrated form if they wish.)

Comment: When are you using GET and when are you using POST?

Comment: In routes.rb I had (match "/signup" => "profiles#new", :as => "signup") and (root :to => "users#new"). It's clear I need to brush up here on SO.